# Azure App Service: "There is not enough space on the disk." Although 300MB/50GB

Tags: azure, storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We have an app service running in a service plan which has a storage limit of 50GB.

The app service is the only one part of the service plan.

We have a .NET web service running on `D:\home\site\services>` with an folder where we periodically create `.docx` and `.pdf` files.

A couple of months ago, we only received `There is not enough space on the disk` after storing multiple gigabytes in that upload folder. But after time, that exception was thrown sooner and sooner - which we fixed by emptying the upload folder.

By now, we get this exception when there is even less than 100 of files in the upload folder. Although the total storage of the app service is only at 400MB/50GB...

Here's the top part of the stacktrace:

```
System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Xceed.Words.NET.DocX.Save()
   at Xceed.Words.NET.DocX.SaveAs(String filename)
```

Does anyone know what we're doing wrong?

**EDIT:** both the app service, and the app service plan has a quota of 50GB. I don't see any storage limits hit at all.

Comment: Did you use  [ASP.NET FileUpload control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to upload files?

Comment: No, these files are generated by our code and then converted to PDF.

Comment: did you find the reason

Comment: still an issue in 2022, uploading 200MB with 1GB of storage and only 172MB used.. tells me disk is full. This is a brand new app service plan/web app with nothing else on it..